# Is this SRP violation?

Tags: design, architecture, single-responsibility

Consider I have a class which represents a tree element. An element can be changed, inspected children elements can be added to it (say trough the `add()` method). But also I have a class which contains **root** of the tree (`State`). And for convenience's sake I have added static overload of `add()` method which adds elements to root. And as result element class needs to get current application state through a singleton (which existence is justified) and therefore element class is bound to `State` class. Is it good? Is it justified? Because otherwise I have to add method `add` to `State` (but this seems like SRP violation though).

Comment: No, it doesn't sound like an SRP violation to me.  Is there any particular reason why you're treating the root of the t ree differently than all of the other nodes?  Every other node is also the root of a tree.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you mean why I store root in other class? Or why the static `add` adds to root?

Comment: Most trees don't require special operations for the root, because each node is *already a root to another tree.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey probably I spoke incorrectly. Root is also an element, but instance of the element which represents root is contained as field/member/property in different class State (because I have to store root somewhere)

Comment: Any reason why it is not `State.root.add`?

Comment: @Theraot because actually it's something like this `Singleton::get()->getStatesManager()->getCurrentState()->getRoot()->add()` instead of `Element::add()`

Comment: Well, here is an idea: `Element::getRoot()->add()`.

Comment: "because I have to store root somewhere" That's not really a great reason to use a static (class level) variable.  There are lot's of places you can store references.  Is there a specific reason you need a static reference to this?

Comment: @JimmyJames Did I say anything about storing root in static var? It is stored in usual field. Only singleton instance's static

Comment: That's what I thought you meant by "But also I have a class which contains root of the tree (State)".  Even if you are referencing it through the singleton, it's just a layer of indirection.  Singletons (as they are typically implemented) are really just global variables with some extra ceremony.  A lot of people would argue they are never justified.  I wouldn't go that far but I don't think they are necessary in any application.

Comment: Singletons are never justified.

Comment: @Telastyn I'm not gonna start another holy war round. But: this singleton represents framework. There's not **any reason** to instantiate two frameworks at the same time. So you're maybe wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The SRP is not about doing one thing, but [about reasons to change](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html).

The case that you describe is on one side a `Tree` class that manages elements, and on the other side a `State` class that makes use of a specific tree.

At first sight, creating an overload to enrich `Tree` with an `add` at root level does not seem to break the SRP: this overload does not create a new reason for change. It's just a convenience.

Unfortunately, it's not fully clear how `root` relates to a node of the `Tree`:

- Is there only one single `root` for all the `Tree` elements? In this case, it's not about SRP but it's more about OCP and extending `Tree` to allow reusability.
- Are there several trees, each with it's own root?  In this case, how do you find the right root? There are two variants:

  - There's no direct relation: the using context has to know its root.  In this case, `State` would have a root. But other classes could have a different root.  Then your `add()` overload would belong to `State` since it addresses an encapsulated element.  But the `add()` signature would depend on the `Tree::add()`. In this case you would break SRP.
  - There is a relation.  For example, each tree would point to a root node.  Or each tree would point to a parent tree, allowing to go back to the root. Or the tree keeps trace of the root, and the tree elements are a nested class.  Whatever the design, you could then have an `add()` for the root level without breaking any SOLID principles.